# Make an entity follow a path manipulating the angle

Tags: java, angle

I'm making a simple test program to try and develop a bullet hell game, but my problem is that I want to make an entity move in a desired path, and I don't know where to start.

Their movement system works by having an angle, and making it's cos and sin the x and y vectors for it's movement (that's the method my teacher taught me). Here's the part of the code that involves that

```
        this.dx = Math.cos(Math.toRadians(angle));
        this.dy = Math.sin(Math.toRadians(angle));
}

public void tick() {
        x+=dx*speed;
        y+=dy*speed;

        //this makes it reverse when the window's wall
        if(x > Game.WIDTH || x < 0) {
            dx = -dx;
        }
        if(y > Game.HEIGHT || y < 0) {
            dy = -dy;
        }

        //this is here so angles are stored correctly
        if(angle < 0) {
            angle += Math.PI*2;
        }else if(angle > Math.PI*2) {
            angle -= Math.PI*2;
        }
}
```

But as I've said, I want it to follow a path I choose. I could specify it with an equation or another method (I really don't know what's more practical), but I don't know how to manipulate the angle to make it follow my desired path.

While I'm making this question, I've figured how to make a circle

```
angle -= 0.05;
        this.dx = Math.cos(angle);
        this.dy = Math.sin(angle);
```

but I'd like to have a way to feed in an equation and manipulate the angle in the right way as to make them follow the path the equation provides on a graph

Answer (score 0):

I have a few different potential ideas that might be what you're looking for:

**Option 1:**
If you want it to follow a smooth path defined by a line on a graph, you could try to parameterise the equation, e.g. have both x and y depend on a variable t, rather than having x and y depend on one another. Then, you can use time as this parameter t, and set the entity's x and y directly based on plugging the time into the parametric equations rather than setting an angle.

**Option 2:**
If you're okay with the path not being a perfectly smooth curve, you could store the path as just a sequence of points in space. The entity stores which point it's currently heading towards and once that point is within a certain distance it moves onto heading towards the next point instead

**Note:**
With option 1, it involves updating the entity's x and y directly instead of setting an angle. If you do still want to update the angle so that the entity faces / fires in the direction it's moving, then you could keep track of where the entity is in the previous tick. Then using it's current position and previous position you can get a vector of the direction it's moving in, and use that to set the angle.